# bootstrap footer searchbar in mobileview get smaller

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

how can i make my bootstrap searchbar footer expand in row in my mobile view. In my desktop view it looks fine but when i go in mobile view 355 x 753 pixels view the footer search bar get smaller. I provided a screenshot in it below:

[image: Screenshot of footer 355 x 753 view]

I want to make my bootstrap footer searchbar take some space in right row of my footer in mobile view.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 pull-left">
<div class="col-xs-7 input-group">  
    <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" class="form-control stylesearch" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Search" /><span class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-search fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button> </span>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

css code w/ media query in (max-width 480px) :

```
.col-xs-5 {
   width:49.667%
   margin-left:-10px;
}
.pull-left {
   margin-bottom:0.9%;
   margin-top:1.1%;
}
.btn-default {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border-color: #e1e1e1;
    color: #333;
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  the second div class to full width `col-xs-12`, if dis doesn work change the class for the div to a larger number and the class of the social icons to 12 - the larger number of the first to stay on the same row

Do the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 pull-left">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 input-group">  
    <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" class="form-control stylesearch" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Search" /><span class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-search fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button> </span>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. if i touch the xs size, the pc view will be destroyed also

Comment: use the alternatives for the pc man `sm,lg,xl` read the documentation on the bootstrap homepage first and then dive into coding